# How to install Google or-tools on AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, or-tools

I've been successfully using [Google's `or-tools`](https://github.com/google/or-tools) on AWS EC2 instances but have recently been looking into including them in AWS Lambda functions but can't get it to run.

### Function `debug.py`

Below is just a basic function importing the `pywrapcp` from `ortools` which should succeed if everything is set up correctly.

```py
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp

def handler(event, context):
    print(pywrapcp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    handler(None, None)
```

### Failing Module Import

I created a `package.sh` script that copies all dependencies to the project  following Amazon's [instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) before creating a zip archive. Running the deployed code results in this:

```
Unable to import module 'debug': No module named ortools.constraint_solver
```

---

**Contents of `package.sh`**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

DEST_DIR=$(dirname $(realpath -s $0));

echo "Copy all native libraries...";
mkdir -p ./lib && find $directory -type f -name "*.so" | xargs cp -t ./lib;

echo "Create package...";
zip -r dist.zip debug.py lib;
rm -r ./lib;

echo "Add dependencies from $VIRTUAL_ENV to $DEST_DIR/dist.zip";

cd $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages;
zip -ur $DEST_DIR/dist.zip ./** -x;
```

When I copy the `ortools` folder from `ortools-4.4.3842-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg` directly into the project root it finds `ortools` but then fails to import `pywrapcp` which may be related to a failure loading the native libraries but I'm not sure since the logs don't show much detail.

```
Unable to import module 'debug': cannot import name pywrapcp
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the discussion on [Google `or-tools`](https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/259) I put together a packaging script that works around the issues installing the dependencies in a way that works for AWS Lambda.

They key part of it is that the contents of the egg packages have to be copied manually to the Lambda project folder and been given the correct permission for them the be accessible during runtime.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

easy_install3 py3-ortools

find "/opt/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages" -path "*.egg/*" -not -name "EGG-INFO" -maxdepth 2 -exec cp -r {} ./dist \;

chmod -R 755 ./dist
```

Instead of creating and configuring an EC2 instance, you can use Docker to create a deployable package locally, see [`or-tools-lambda`](https://github.com/christianklotz/or-tools-lambda) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the underlying AWS Lambda execution environment is Amazon Linux while or-tools is not tested beyond the below environments as per https://github.com/google/or-tools

- Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 up (64-bit).
- Mac OS X El Capitan with Xcode 7.x (64 bit).
- Microsoft Windows with Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 (64-bit)

Test your code by launching an instance with one of the ami's which aws lambda uses in the list here (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html)

If it works, use pip to install dependencies/libraries at the root level of your project directory and then zip. Do not copy the libraries manually to your project directory

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From what I can tell running my code using `or-tools` it works well with AMI on an EC2 instance if I install `or-tools` using the recommended installation route by downloading `ortools-examples`. It seems more of an issue of getting the dependencies packaged up correctly. 

I haven't tried setting the root level for `pip` or `python setup.py` on an EC2 instance yet, only ran https://gist.github.com/christianklotz/46270402552911e73d589072a8f76e56 for installing `or-tools`.

Comment: There are some steps for troubleshooting the Python or-tools installation (https://developers.google.com/optimization/installing).
There is a mention for installing using pip (pip install ortools). If this works, for lambda to pickup dependency correctly, try "pip install ortools -t /path/to/project-dir".